# pandas get the max of column datetime value sums for each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the max out of column sums for each row and assign the max value to a new column,

```
df['due_date'] = df.apply(
        lambda x: max(x['days_1'] + x['baseline_date'],
                      x['days_2'] + x['baseline_date'],
                      x['days_3'] + x['baseline_date']), axis=1)
```

the 'df' looks like.

```
days_1    days_2    days_3    baseline_date
0         0         0         2018-01-01
12        0         0         2017_01-01
0         3         0         2016-01-01
0         0         4         2015-01-01
```

`baseline_date` is of `datetime` `dtype`, `days_1/2/3` are of `int` type.

the code gave me

```
ValueError: ('Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq.', 'occurred at index 0')
```

I am wondering how to get the max date acquired by `base_line_date` + `days1/2/3`.

Comment: whats it the dtype of baseline_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `max` with `axis = 1`

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.iloc[:,:3].max(1),'D')+pd.to_datetime(df.baseline_date)
Out[437]: 
0   2018-01-01
1   2017-01-13
2   2016-01-04
3   2015-01-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

you should convert your days* columns to pd.Timeadelta.

you can use apply with lambda function

```
df[daylikecolumne].apply(lambda c: pd.Timedelta(c,'D'))
```

this way you can add subtract between compatible datypes e.g. timedelta and datetime